# Borrar cadena parcialmente con sed o similar

Tags: linux, bash, script, sed

Tengo un archivo en el que se puede ver por ejemplo:

```
[Num_5]asd [Num_/]fgh[Num_7][Num_8]
[Num_+][Num_9][alarm]
25[Num_3][Num_7] mnb
```

Y quiero borrar el "[NUM_" y el "]" para que se quede así:

```
5asd /fgh78
+9[alarm]
2537 mnb
```

El primero lo puedo quitar con `sed 's/\[Num_//g'` pero se me queda el corchete compañero sólo y es más difícil quitarlo sin borrar todos los corchetes, creo que habría que quitar primero el "]" y después el "[NUM_" o ambos a la vez pero no soy capaz de hacerlo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

test.txt:

```
[Num_5]asd [Num_/]fgh[Num_7][Num_8]
[Num_+][Num_9][alarm]
25[Num_3][Num_7] mnb
```

comando:

```
sed -E 's/\[Num_(.?)\]/\1/g' test.txt
```

1. `\1` selecciona el grupo 1
2. `.` encuentra cualquier carácter excepto los caracteres de nueva linea
3. `?` elemento precedente 0 o una vez

resultado:

```
5asd /fgh78
+9[alarm]
2537 mnb
```

si quieres que sea a caracteres especificos:

```
sed -E 's/\[Num_([1-9+/]+)\]/\1/g'
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba. Siento no tener reputación suficiente para votarla.